# If there is a unique left identity, then it is also a right identity

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $(R,+,\cdot)$ be a ring, and $e \in R$ be an element such that $ea=a$ for all $a\in R$. I'm trying to prove that if $e$ is unique with this property, then $ae=a$ for all $a\in R $.

So far I have $e^2 = e$ (using uniqueness), but I am stuck. I saw a proof of this fact for groups which used the existence of inverses, which we don't have here. I wonder if the result is really true here. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need uniqueness to prove $e^2=e$?

Comment: $e^2a = e(ea) = ea = a$. By uniqueness, $e^2= e$.

Comment: Or simply let $a=e$, isn't it?

Comment: What Solid Snake means is that you get this for free by setting $a=e$.

Comment: Oh, crap. So uniqueness must come in somewhere else

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Let $b \in R$. Then
$$(be-b+e)a=a \forall a \in R$$

By the uniqueness you get
$$be-b+e=e$$

As $b \in R$ is arbitrary, you are done.

Comment: Man, I'm feeling so stupid. We solved an exercise about $be - b + e $ like, $10$ minutes ago. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Amazing answer, I think.

Comment: Very nice. You have to use addition because an associative monoid can have a unique left identity and no right identity.